# Zooming specific elemens on paper

Tags: javascript, raphael, zooming, scale

How can i zoom in the specific symbols on the paper. What I mean is, I can able to zoom whole page, but now I want to zoom in the specific elements.

While googling I found one example. However in those it is only scaling.

Do you have idea how can I zoom?

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/6MVFQ/)***

You can use the semi standard css `zoom`, and semi compliant `-moz-transform: scale(x);` on an element. As noted, this will only scale it. In order to zoom it, or to mimic a real zoom, you will have to wrap it in a relatively positioned element, and place the scaled content in a absolutely positioned element. Here is an example:

html

```
<div class="holder"><div id="d">No Zoom</div></div>
<div class="holder"><div id="a">Zoom</div></div>
```

css

```
#d, #a{
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

.holder{
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
 width:90px;
 height:90px;
 background-color:blue;
 color:white;
 border: 2px solid black;
 padding:10px;
}
```

js

```
var a = document.getElementById("a");
a.onmouseover = function(){
 this.setAttribute("style","zoom: 5;-moz-transform:scale(5);");
};
a.onmouseout = function(){
 this.removeAttribute("style");
};
```

Comment: I think is only again scaling. And do you know how to do only with javascript

Comment: @NevzatOrhan - Yes, isn't scaling zooming? See the edit for an example with pure javascript.

Comment: Actually it is a little bit different. Here is the link explaining this.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/153998/whats-the-difference-between-zoom-and-scale-in-gimp